# Split a string using a list of strings as a pattern

Tags: python, regex, split

Consider an input string :

```
mystr = "just some stupid string to illustrate my question"
```

and a list of strings indicating where to split the input string:

```
splitters = ["some", "illustrate"]
```

The output should look like

```
result = ["just ", "some stupid string to ", "illustrate my question"]
```

I wrote some code which implements the following approach. For each of the strings in `splitters`, I find its occurrences in the input string, and insert something which I know for sure would not be a part of my input string (for example, this `'!!'`). Then I split the string using the substring that I just inserted.

```
for s in splitters:
    mystr = re.sub(r'(%s)'%s,r'!!\1', mystr)

result = re.split('!!', mystr)
```

This solution seems ugly, is there a nicer way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Splitting with `re.split` will always remove the matched string from the output (*NB, this is not quite true, see the edit below*). Therefore, you must use positive lookahead expressions (`(?=...)`) to match without removing the match. However, `re.split` **ignores empty matches**, so simply using a lookahead expression doesn't work. Instead, you **will lose one character at each split** at minimum (even trying to trick `re` with "boundary" matches (`\b`) does not work). If you don't care about losing one whitespace / non-word character at the end of each item (assuming you only split at non-word characters), you can use something like

```
re.split(r"\W(?=some|illustrate)")
```

which would give

```
["just", "some stupid string to", "illustrate my question"]
```

(note that the spaces after `just` and `to` are missing). You could then programmatically generate these regexes using `str.join`. Note that each of the split markers is escaped with `re.escape` so that special characters in the items of `splitters` do not affect the meaning of the regular expression in any undesired ways (imagine, e.g., a `)` in one of the strings, which would otherwise lead to a regex syntax error).

```
the_regex = r"\W(?={})".format("|".join(re.escape(s) for s in splitters))
```

**Edit** (*HT to [@Arkadiy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412996/split-a-string-using-a-list-of-strings-as-a-pattern#comment39642468_25413153)*): Grouping the actual match, i.e. using `(\W)` instead of `\W`, returns the non-word characters inserted into the list as seperate items. Joining every two subsequent items would then produce the list as desired as well. Then, you can also drop the requirement of having a non-word character by using `(.)` instead of `\W`:

```
the_new_regex = r"(.)(?={})".format("|".join(re.escape(s) for s in splitters))
the_split = re.split(the_new_regex, mystr)
the_actual_split = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest(the_split[::2], the_split[1::2], fillvalue='')]
```

Because normal text and auxiliary character alternate, `the_split[::2]` contains the normal split text and `the_split[1::2]` the auxiliary characters. Then, `itertools.izip_longest` is used to combine each text item with the corresponding removed character and the last item (which is unmatched in the removed characters)) with `fillvalue`, i.e. `''`. Then, each of these tuples is joined using `"".join(x)`. Note that this requires `itertools` to be imported (you could of course do this in a simple loop, but `itertools` provides very clean solutions to these things). Also note that `itertools.izip_longest` is called `itertools.zip_longest` in Python 3.

This leads to further simplification of the regular expression, because instead of using auxiliary characters, the lookahead can be replaced with a simple matching group (`(some|interesting)` instead of `(.)(?=some|interesting)`):

```
the_newest_regex = "({})".format("|".join(re.escape(s) for s in splitters))
the_raw_split = re.split(the_newest_regex, mystr)
the_actual_split = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest([""] + the_raw_split[1::2], the_raw_split[::2], fillvalue='')]
```

Here, the slice indices on `the_raw_split` have swapped, because now the even-numbered items must be added to item afterwards instead of in front. Also note the `[""] +` part, which is necessary to pair the first item with `""` to fix the order.

**(end of edit)**

Alternatively, you can (if you want) use `string.replace` instead of `re.sub` for each splitter (I think that is a matter of preference in your case, but in general it is probably more efficient)

```
for s in splitters:
    mystr = mystr.replace(s, "!!" + s)
```

Also, if you use a fixed token to indicate where to split, you do not need `re.split`, but can use `string.split` instead:

```
result = mystr.split("!!")
```

What you could also do (instead of relying on the replacement token not to be in the string anywhere else or relying on every split position being preceded by a non-word character) is finding the split strings in the input using `string.find` and using string slicing to extract the pieces:

```
def split(string, splitters):
    while True:
        # Get the positions to split at for all splitters still in the string
        # that are not at the very front of the string
        split_positions = [i for i in (string.find(s) for s in splitters) if i > 0]
        if len(split_positions) > 0:
            # There is still somewhere to split
            next_split = min(split_positions)
            yield string[:next_split] # Yield everything before that position
            string = string[next_split:] # Retain the rest of the string
        else:
            yield string # Yield the rest of the string
            break # Done.
```

Here, `[i for i in (string.find(s) for s in splitters) if i > 0]` generates a list of positions where the splitters can be found, for all splitters that are in the string (for this, `i < 0` is excluded) and not right at the beginning (where we (possibly) just split, so `i == 0` is excluded as well). If there are any left in the string, we yield (this is a generator function) everything up to (excluding) the first splitter (at `min(split_positions)`) and replace the string with the remaining part. If there are none left, we yield the last part of the string and exit the function. Because this uses `yield`, it is a generator function, so you need to use `list` to turn it into an actual list.

Note that you could also replace `yield whatever` with a call to `some_list.append` (provided you defined `some_list` earlier) and return `some_list` at the very end, I do not consider that to be very good code style, though.

---

#### TL;DR

If you are OK with using regular expressions, use

```
the_newest_regex = "({})".format("|".join(re.escape(s) for s in splitters))
the_raw_split = re.split(the_newest_regex, mystr)
the_actual_split = ["".join(x) for x in itertools.izip_longest([""] + the_raw_split[1::2], the_raw_split[::2], fillvalue='')]
```

else, the same can also be achieved using `string.find` with the following split function:

```
def split(string, splitters):
    while True:
        # Get the positions to split at for all splitters still in the string
        # that are not at the very front of the string
        split_positions = [i for i in (string.find(s) for s in splitters) if i > 0]
        if len(split_positions) > 0:
            # There is still somewhere to split
            next_split = min(split_positions)
            yield string[:next_split] # Yield everything before that position
            string = string[next_split:] # Retain the rest of the string
        else:
            yield string # Yield the rest of the string
            break # Done.
```

Comment: you should escape your split words with `re.escape` before joining the regular expression.

Comment: I wonder if `"(\W)(?=some|illustrate)"` and then concatenating every two elements of the list together may work... "If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list"

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes, that would work (adding that now...). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hahaha, such a rigorous answer! Thank you! I should probably have mentioned that white spaces were not of a big importance in my particular application, but I definitely learned a lot from your answer, and now I know many ways of solving the problem ;)

Comment: @ojy I know, that escalated a little while I was working on it... Feel free to mark it as an accepted answer if it helped you

Comment: Of course I was gonna to, just wanted to note that the second to the last piece of code actually misses the 'just ' substring. But whatever, I can infer the solution :)

Comment: @ojy Fixed that issue... the sequences passed to `izip_longest` didn't align properly

Answer (score 4):

Not especially elegant but avoiding regex:

```
mystr = "just some stupid string to illustrate my question"
splitters = ["some", "illustrate"]
indexes = [0] + [mystr.index(s) for s in splitters] + [len(mystr)]
indexes = sorted(list(set(indexes)))

print [mystr[i:j] for i, j in zip(indexes[:-1], indexes[1:])]
# ['just ', 'some stupid string to ', 'illustrate my question']
```

I should acknowledge here that a little more work is needed if a word in `splitters` occurs more than once because `str.index` finds only the location of the first occurrence of the word...

Comment: Yea, there's also a problem when not all the words from splitters are in the string. But I like the mystr.index(), I didn't know about it, +1!

Comment: Thanks! That's true - it will raise `ValueError` if not found. One could get around it by using `str.find` instead: that will return `-1` instead if a word in `splitters` is not in `mystr` (`-1` will then need to be removed from `indexes`, e.g. `set(indexes) - set([-1])`)